# How we can set special price if quantity of products ordered is under certain limit in Magento2

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice

Is their any option in backend or any plugin available ?

I mean as :

if quantity ordered 10 to 20 : Price = 50$

if quantity ordered 20 to 30 : Price = 100$

.
.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally it's called tier pricing.

It is available when you edit a product in the **Advanced Settings > Advanced Pricing** or **under the Price field** depending on your Magento 2 version

In the **Tier Price** area, you need to click the **Add Tier** button and do the following:

- Customer Group: choose to which group this is gonna apply
- Quantity: 20
- Price: 100

Then repeat this step with the following:

- Customer Group: choose to which group this is gonna apply
- Quantity: 10
- Price: 50

Comment: I added as you set but this applies only if quantity is greater than 20  price becomes 50 per peice. I need to apply special price if product count comes under specifid limit .For every limitcustomer group will be : All websites.

Comment: @Narendra.vyas sorry I misread your question I've updated my answer ;)

Comment: For every case when quantity is greater to 10 price is remaining 50$ only ,, its not changing if i increases quantity more then to 20 ?

Comment: @Narendra.vyas with my example if you order between 10 and 20 products, one product will cost 50. If you order more than 20 it will cost 100

Comment: unfortunately i think its not working for me ,,, does this also matter to first set role for quantity : 20 and then for quantity : 10 ..... if so then i shall highlight that its not happening as i provide so on saving the product it shifts automatically to quantity : 10 on upper side than quantity : 20

Comment: @ Raphael at Digital Pianism : Thanks a lot the issue was of browser cache, opened incognito and resolved ..

Comment: @Narendra.vyas glad you fixed it =)